# Using Docker SDK for loading image from a file

Tags: docker, go

I use the ImageLoad function for loading an image:

```
    file, err := os.OpenFile(fileName, os.O_RDONLY, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Debugf("Error loading image %s, %s", fileName, err)
    } else {
        defer file.Close()
        resp, err := client.api.ImageLoad(ctx, file, false)
        if err != nil {
            log.Debugf("Error loading image %s, %s", fileName, err)
        }
        if resp.Body == nil {
            err = errors.New("Error loading image")
        } else {
            defer resp.Body.Close()
        }
    }
```

But I have no error if I load a file which is not image.
If I use the console it works as expected:

```
$ docker load -i s.tar
open /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-import-075289246/repositories: no such file or directory
```

So, why I dont have a error in case of SDK?

Comment: can you please add how are you open file etc?

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added working example for me:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

func main() {
    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv, client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    input := bytes.NewReader([]byte("dummy content\n"))
    imageLoadResponse, err := cli.ImageLoad(context.Background(), input, true)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(imageLoadResponse.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
//Output:
// {"errorDetail":{"message":"Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF"},"error":"Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF"}
```

Also you can review how `docker load` [command](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/75299fd6c26f2a7648321f77f2589f428424e8f0/cli/command/image/load.go#L41-L59)

Comment: ok, I thought ImageLoad must return a error if it cant load a file as an image. So, we should read body for that? We should parse its response? Is there a simple operation?

Comment: yes correct, because under the hood it's just http api call.